# Kids TV show about 4 kids with elemental powers

Tags: story-identification, tv, powers

So around 2008-2009 there used to be this TV show every Saturday about 4 kids that were made up of elemental powers. For example one was made of water, one was made of earth, one was made of wind and one was made of fire. There were some other elements, too. They all had one master, but I can't remember the name of the show.

Answer (score 3):

#### Was it [Xiaolin Showdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Showdown)?

Here is the first paragraph from Wikipedia (emphasis mine to illustrate important aspects of the show):

> **Xiaolin Showdown** is an **American animated television series** that aired **on Kids WB** and was created by Christy Hui. Set in a world where martial arts battles and Eastern magic are commonplace, the series follows four young **Xiaolin warriors in training who battle the Heylin forces of evil**. They do this by protecting **Shen Gong Wu (ancient artifacts that have great magical powers)** from villains that would use them to conquer the world. Typical episodes revolve around a specific Shen Gong Wu being revealed which results in both sides racing to find it. Episodes usually reach a head when one good and one evil character must challenge each other to a magical duel called a Xiaolin Showdown for possession of the artifact.

The main characters are each associated with an element (taken from Wikipedia again):

> - Omi (voiced by Tara Strong) – The Xiaolin Dragon of Water
> - Kimiko Tohomiko (voiced by Grey DeLisle) – The Xiaolin Dragon of Fire
> - Raimundo Pedrosa (voiced by Tom Kenny) – The Xiaolin Dragon of Wind
> - Clay Bailey (voiced by Jeff Bennett) – The Xiaolin Dragon of Earth

And they have one Master:

> - Master Fung (voiced by René Auberjonois in season 1 and Maurice LaMarche in seasons 2-3) The Xiaolin Warrior's Master, trainer, and guide, Master Fung is mortified by his charges' behavior at times.

About the time (emphasis mine again):

> **Originally airing on the Kids' WB block of programming on WB Network from 2003 to 2006**, the series ran for 3 seasons and 52 episodes. **Reruns** also aired on Cartoon Network **from 2006 to 2007**. Xiaolin Chronicles, a direct sequel of the series, was previewed on August 26, 2013 on Disney XD. It began its long-term run on September 14 the same year.[1]